# How to stop sea bass fillets from sticking to foil

Tags: seafood

I've cooked sea bass before on 220 degrees centigrade for 15 minutes baked in the oven. I get some foil and place it on a baking tray and cover it in a thin layer of olive oil. I then place the fillets on top and drizzle over some more olive oil. I fold the tin foil into loose little packets and put it in the oven. 15 minutes later the fillets are stuck to the foil and have to be forced off, ruining the shape of the fish and reducing it to mush.

How can I prevent this? More oil? Which side should I place the fillet down?

Comment: Are these skin-on filets?   If so, skin-side down.

Answer (score 1):

Skin side down will work best, as for how to prevent sticking more oil is the way to go. In my experience wax paper (baking paper or baking parchment to some) works better and sticks less. If you really need the foil (say you are cooking over a fire) then using wax paper inside the foil will give you the result you need.

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this tonight.